# How long do I have to wait for my offer letter?

Tags: phd, application

It's been nearly two months (next week it'll be 2 months) since I got an email from the Doctoral School at a UK university telling me that I got the place and funding. After 4 weeks of waiting, I emailed them to ask when the letter would be sent out but they gave me no specific answer. Also by chance I learned that someone already received their letter nearly 4 weeks ago. I'm very worried and just wondering how long everyone had to wait to get their offer letters. And should I contact them again about it?

Comment: This is too variable to be useful. Your situation is too unique to get any useful answer here. They will do what they do. But in general, if there is a problem you are more likely to hear about it earlier than later. If you have other alternatives to consider then, yes, contact them. But if you can afford to wait then there isn't much downside. Keep pursuing other options, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Pick up the telephone. Repeat several times to several people if first call does not get an answer.

Get this resolved within a week.  Have them send the letter express mail.  No more sitting and pining.  If you haven't resolved it by week end, you need to move on and look for a different gig.

Comment: _Have them send the letter express mail._ — In the US, acceptance/funding letters are usually sent by email, but they still have the same legal weight as paper.  Is that not also true in the UK?

Comment: But can they really revoke the offer once they said they would send it to me?

Comment: @JeffE: I'm not sure about this. But they specifically told me in the email that they would send a separate, official offer letter by email so I imagine the email telling me that I got the place and funding was only an informal notification.